# vbscript function clean string only allow certain characters

Tags: regex, vbscript, string-formatting, sanitization

Until now I've been manually adding characters to replace that break my code.  I'd like to be a bit more proactive, so I found this function that is supposed to replace everything EXCEPT valid characters.  <strike>My first hurdle is that it doesn't seem to work.  The code below is my full test file and the MsgBox comes up blank.</strike>

My second question is about performance.  This function handles very, very large strings.  Will this method be considerably slower?  Anyone recommend anything else?

```
    Function CleanUp (input)
      Dim objRegExp, outputStr
      Set objRegExp = New Regexp

      objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
      objRegExp.Global = True
      objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9]).)+"
      outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(input, "-")

      objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
      outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "-")

      CleanUp = outputStr
    End Function

    MsgBox (CleanUp("Test"))
```

**Edit: I'm stupid and just saw the variable mixup I did which was causing it to return nothing.  It is working now.  Will still accept input for performance question or better suggestions.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it even further.

objRegExp.Pattern = "[^\w+]"

Comment: Can you please explain what ^\w+ stands for?

Comment: The \w in the pattern is a character class that will match any word character. This is equivalent to [a-zA-Z_0-9].  The ^ indicates the beginning of the string.  So this pattern will match a string of word characters in a row starting from the immediate beginning of the string and ending that last word character or the end of the string, whichever is encountered first.

Answer (score 2):

It don't know what is the expected result for your example, but maybe you can try that for the pattern instead:

objRegExp.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"

Hope it works